# Find dash "-" that's not inside round brackets "()" within String

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to find/determine if a String contains the character "-" that is not enclosed in round brackets "()".

I've tried the regex
`[^\(]*-[^\)]*`,
but it's not working.

Examples:

1. `100 - 200 mg` -> should match because the "-" is not enclosed in round brackets.
2. `100 (+/-) units` -> should NOT match

Comment: Um...it seems to be working for me...

Comment: I would just look for the simple match and check if non match found to evaluate it. 

For ex: `\(.*-.*\)` I would use this regex to match `-` within braces and check for the failure to match any expression as a positive in Java. Much easier and probably fool proof

Comment: @CalebH. Pasting this code into [RegExr](https://regexr.com/4dvsf), it looks like their regex doesn't work. I think the problem is the * quantifier that matches **zero or more** characters. This will match with the (+/-) example, since can be **zero** non-parenthesis characters next to the dash (as is the case on the right side).

Comment: When I came to it, there wasn't a * at the end.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to escape brackets inside a character class. ie `[^\(]` is identical with `[^(]`

Comment: @CalebH. that was a formatting issue in the question - the OP hadn't used backquotes so that * was interpreted as "italics". I edited the question to use backquotes but I didn't change the regex.

Comment: @SamanthaMiller This is a Java question, where presumably OP is calling `matches` (on [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) or [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches--)), not `find` (on `Matcher`), and `matches` matches the entire string, not just a substring, i.e. has implied `^` and `$` anchors. As such, the regex works fine.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt ah, I see. Now that makes sense.

Comment: Have you tried https://ideone.com/YXvuem (posted [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56141033/3832970))? I believe it is the solution you need.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to use regex? You could try just iterating over the string and keeping track of the scope like so:

```
public boolean HasScopedDash(String str)
{
    int scope = 0;
    boolean foundInScope = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if (c == '(')
            scope++;
        else if (c == '-')
            foundInScope = scope != 0;
        else if (c == ')' && scope > 0)
        {
            if (foundInScope)
                return true;
            scope--;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Edit: As mentioned in the comments, it might be desirable to exclude cases where the dash comes after an opening parenthesis but no closing parenthesis ever follows. (I.e. "abc(2-xyz") The above edited code accounts for this.

Comment: There is no guarantee of balanced or matched parenthesis. Therefore this won't work in cases which have no closure like `asdf(sdf-afb` . That's why you actually have to find the closure to test it. Bring in regex, that's what it does.

Comment: The OP didn't specify that that was a requirement. Depending on the situation it might even be desired that that case doesn't return true.

Comment: `"-" that is not enclosed in round brackets "()"` So, you need to find _closure_. Can't assume closure. Either   `a(-)b` and fail, or `a(-b` and pass.

Comment: Fair enough. I assumed the input string would've been cleansed/controlled. It'd be trivial to tweak the code to account for that though. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Could also be something like `int scope = 0;
    bool bHaveDash = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if (c == '(')
            scope++;
        else
        if (c == ')' && scope > 0)
            scope--;
        else
        if (c == '-')
        {
            if (scope == 0)
                return true;
            bHaveDash = true;
        }
        if (scope == 0)
            bHaveDash = false;
    }
    return bHaveDash;`

Answer (score 0):

You might not to want to check for that to make this pass. Maybe, you could simply make a check on other boundaries. This expression for instance checks for spaces and numbers before and after the dash or any other chars in the middle you wish to have, which is much easier to modify:

```
([0-9]\s+[-]\s+[0-9])
```

It passes your first input and fails the undesired input. You could simply add other chars to its middle char list using logical ORs.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vcIKZZ/1/)

[image]

Comment: `[-]` is more simply written as `-`.

Answer (score 0):

Java supports quantified atomic groups, this works.
The way it works is to consume paired parenthesis and their contents,
and not giving anything back, up until it finds a  dash `-`.
This is done via the *atomic group* constructs `(?> )`.

`^(?>(?>\(.*?\))|[^-])*?-`

https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyd8n1dar
(click on the Java button, check the *`find()`* function column)

Readable

```
 ^ 
 (?>
      (?> \( .*? \) )
   |  
      [^-] 
 )*?
 -
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind to check the string by using 2 regex instead of 1 complicated regex. You can try this instead

```
public static boolean match(String input) {
    Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\-"); // match dash
    Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("\\(.*\\-.*\\)"); // match dash within bracket

    Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(input);
    Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(input);

    if ( m1.find() && !m2.find() ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Test the string

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input1 = "100 - 200 mg";
    String input2 = "100 (+/-) units";
    System.out.println(input1 + " : " + ( match(input1) ? "match" : "not match") );
    System.out.println(input2 + " : " + ( match(input2) ? "match" : "not match") );
}
```

The output will be

```
100 - 200 mg : match
100 (+/-) units : not match
```

Comment: This will work for what I'm trying to accomplish. Thank You!!1

Answer (score 0):

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\([^()-]*-[^()]*\\)").matcher(s); return !m.find();
```

https://ideone.com/YXvuem